# Big arrow in El Capital icon alias

Tags: macos

Do you know what it means these big arrows in the icon alias? I know that the small arrows means that this is an alias (a kind of symbolic link).

[image: Big and small alias in Mac OS X]

Answer (score 0):

Those arrows mean that the icon is really a shortcut to an executable file, or link.

The big arrows appears to just be blown up for some reason.  It's likely still a shortcut.

If you right click on the icon, and inspect its properties, it should tell you where that shortcut points to (on Windows at least, not sure about Mac).